# How can I use "PowerShell FTP Client Module" with TortoiseHg to automate deployment of committed changes?

Tags: powershell, deployment, ftp, tortoisehg

**Background:**
I am maintaining a simple html/php website: http://www.archskirt.com.au/index.php

I edit a local copy of the site using notepad++, I use TortoiseHg v4.0 for version control, and I upload changes to the live site using FileZilla v3.24. I want to use "[PowerShell FTP Client Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb)"
to automate my deployment process so that it is faster and less prone to human error. I'm super new to PowerShell and its Integrated Scripting Environment, and I struggle to understand more than half of what is said in "introductory" guides.

**Here is my current code** inside pushtotest.ps1

```
##### Establish a connection to ftp.server.com.au #####
Import-Module PSFTP

$FTPServer = 'ftp.server.com.au'
$FTPUsername = 'username'
$FTPPassword = 'password'
$FTPSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $FTPPassword -asPlainText -Force
$FTPCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($FTPUsername,$FTPSecurePassword)

Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $FTPServer -Session MySession -UsePassive 
$Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession 

##### Get list of files that have changed from TortoiseHG #####
Set-Location -path c:\xampp\htdocs\
$changeList = hg status --change . -n
echo $changeList

##### Copy files from local directory to live directory #####

ForEach ($file in $changeList) {
  $fileName = (Get-Item $file).Name
  echo $fileName

  $localPath = (Get-Item $file).FullName
  echo $localPath

  $relativePath = ??
  echo $relativePath

  Add-FTPItem -path "/home/server/public_html/$relativePath" -localpath $localPath -Overwrite
}
```

The results from echo $changeList are:

```
file.php
subdir\file4.php
subdir\file7.php
subdir\subdir2\file11.php
```

The results from echo $fileName are:

```
file.php
file4.php
file7.php
file11.php
```

The results from echo $localPath are:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\file.php
c:\xampp\htdocs\subdir\file4.php
c:\xampp\htdocs\subdir\file7.php
c:\xampp\htdocs\subdir\subdir2\file11.php
```

**What I think I need** is for $relativePath to contain the same thing as $changeList, but without the filename. I am unsure how to do this.

**Bonus Question:** Will my code work when I put a variable containing backslashes into a path written with forward slashes? For example:

```
Add-FTPItem -path "/home/server/public_html/$relativePath"
```